# Capping off a single (large) wire?

Tags: wire

I have a five-conductor 2 AWG cable (three phases, neutral, and ground) connected into a 22.5 kVA (i.e., very big and dangerous) power supply. This is being used for research relating to ground faults, so the points at which the system is grounded are carefully controlled, and the ground wire is not connected to the power supply, though it does need to be present (even if it didn't, it's a five-conductor cable and we can't exactly pull one of the conductors out without unreasonable force that would risk damaging the other conductors).

So the question is this: how can I safely terminate this single 2 AWG wire in a manner that keeps it well-insulated from the power supply chassis? I was thinking of using a wire nut to just cap off the single wire, but there don't seem to be any designed to take a 2 AWG wire. Is there a keyword I can use to search for these?

Edit: also of note is that this is a ground wire and will be at ground potential, it just can't be connected to ground here. The other cables at the power supply output are carrying no more than 600 V (actually, the power supply might only go up to 500 V) so there's no high voltage that risks multi-centimeter arcs or corona discharge or anything.

Comment: If its for research only (i.e. non-permanent installation), just wrap the end in electrical tape.

Comment: @TomCarpenter This is for research, yes, but it's a permanent piece of apparatus that will be used for a variety of research over at least three years and probably much more, so it's probably best to treat it as a permanent installation.

Comment: Maybe a porcelain insulator? A picture of the cable installation would help.

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 I don't have a picture, unfortunately, but I can take one on monday if someone hasn't answered by then. Should have thought to take one earlier when I was on site.

Comment: This is the sort of question you should ask of a licensed electrician. I'm migrating this to DIY, which is where such people hang out.

Comment: are you familiar with 600V arc flash regulations? and spontaneous human combustion from faulty insulation?

Comment: Multi-cm arcs may be possible if they get started, depending on the fault current.

Comment: attach it to a covered terminal strip

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Cold-Shrink-Silicone-Insulator-8445-7-5-2-1-0-AWG-35-50-mm-12-per-case/?N=5002385%203294759112&rt=rud) is one possibility- "cold shrink" silicone insulator. Check the voltage rating for whatever type you are looking at.

You pull on the end of the coiled plastic and it unravels, leaving the silicone cap to shrink onto the end of the wire.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Only rated for 1kV

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 I don't see a voltage given, just a power. Okay, apparently it's effectively 600V so 1kV should be fine.

Comment: Shielding Type
 Tape Shield, UniShield®, Wire Shield
Shrink Ratio
 2:1
Splice Type
 Cold Shrink
Trademark
 3M
Voltage
 1 kV

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 OP's voltage is only 600V. It's 22kVA not 22kV.

Comment: i see better now but lightning transients will not be withstood

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 It's likely no worse than the actual insulation on the cable itself.

Comment: I cleaned my glasses now. Yes wirenuts then taped tight could be  fine if the ground faults don't include creating arcs or voltage transients just like at home when attached to the big ass grid with a breaker and pulling out a large powered motor plug.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Sure. It's not that scary an installation, about the same current (~50A) as my hobby kiln but at 480VAC rather than 240VAC. https://xkcd.com/37/

Comment: Not nearly as high voltage as my taped unused kV 4 output fluorescent ballast drivers but then there are fire codes for power grid unused wires to be insulated and secured in safety outlet boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There are standards in each country to follow, like using an interior or exterior junction box  with a taped wirenut on wire.

If the warning label disappeared . Should someone guess if the loose live wire is live but looks dead?  Who will know what ground fault tests may be done in future to induce a few kV transients to stress a possible loosened wirenut and short circuit creating an arc **flash fire**.

Don't do a Mickey Mouse job.

Answer (score 0):

At number 2 wire that is not live I would use super88 electrical tape. Industrial electricians use split bolts to join larger wires then a layer of cambric tape like 2520 then a layer of rubber tape 130c and finish off with super88. Some will use super33 but 88 is thicker and resist punctures better.  Since the wire won't be used as a conductor the tape is a way of identifying it is not in use and will protect from any induced (phantom) voltage on the wire 480v  phantom voltages can bite enough to wake you up with the right conditions. 480 being the standard in the U.S. for heavy industrial, I know there are voltages from 208-500 across the pond and super 88 will protect there also.